# How do I make the cloned SXA map component work?

Tags: sxa

I cloned the SXA map component and named it Custom map.Dropped it to the page with all the fields values set (latitude, longitude etc.) similar to SXA map component (see screenshot). The location gets plotted for map component but not for the custom map component :(. I have made no change in the custom map rendering, its templates or code thus far after cloning. Am I missing something ?[image]

Comment: New observation- If I select Map template as the data source template for the custom map rendering, then it works. What is wrong with the Custom map template ? Both Map template and Custom map template looks similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all paces in SXA, we are checking inheritance (base templates) of items. Thanks to this you can have your templates for different purposes but still making them to recognise by SXA.

Because of above your custom map data source item needs to inherit from the default map data source. Please also check base templates of the original map data source template. If there will be any additional ones, assign them to your custom map rendering data source item too